# htonl without using network related headers

Tags: c++, c, networking

We are writing an embedded application code and validating a string for a valid IPv4 format. I am successfully able to do so using string tokenizer but now I need to convert the integers to Host-To-Network order using htonl() function.

Since it an embedded application I cannot include network header and library just to make use of htonl() function.

Is there any way / non-network header in C++ by which I can avail htonl() functionality?

Comment: You could take the implementation of `htonl` and include in the relevant compilation unit.

Comment: "*convert the string to Host-To-Network*" What? `hton*()` converts integers not strings.

Comment: Made the required change in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`htonl()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl)'s man page:

> The htonl() function converts the unsigned integer hostlong from host byte order to network byte order.

[Network byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Networking) is actually just big endian.

All you need to do is write (or find) a function that converts an unsigned integer to big endian and use it in place of `htonl`. If your system is already in big endian than you don't need to do anything at all.

---

You can use the following to determine the endianness of your system:

```
int n = 1;
// little endian if true
if(*(char *)&n == 1) {...}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4181991/9614249)

---

And you can convert a little endian `uint32_t` to big endian using the following:

```
uint32_t htonl(uint32_t x) {
    unsigned char *s = (unsigned char *)&x;
    return (uint32_t)(s[0] << 24 | s[1] << 16 | s[2] << 8 | s[3]);
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708182/about-the-source-code-of-htonl)

Comment: Unfortunately, checking the host byte order like that is implementation defined behaviour; while it will probably always work as intended I'd try to avoid code like that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't strictly need htonl. If you have the IP address as individual bytes like this:

```
uint8_t a [4] = { 192, 168, 2, 1 };
```

You can just send these 4 bytes, in that exact order, over the network. That is unless you specifically need it as a 4 byte Integer, which you probably don't, since you presumably are not using sockaddr_in & friends.

If you already have the address as a 32 bit integer in host byte order, you can obtain `a` like this:

```
uint32_t ip = getIPHostOrder();
uint8_t a [4] = { (ip >> 24) & 0xFF, (ip >> 16) & 0xFF, (ip >> 8) & 0xFF, ip & 0xFF };
```

This has the advantage of not relying on implementation defined behaviour and being portable.

Comment: Maybe I am dumb for not seeing it, but how does this work on big and little endian systems?

Comment: Thanks - but mine's code is a function returning in Host-Tio-Netwrok format - so upper interfaces layer are writing the value

Comment: @Erlkoenig Doesn't this still depend on a certain host byte order?

Comment: No, it should work regardless of host order. htonl is actually just a dirty little trick to allow using sockaddr_in. If you can send individual bytes (like the a array) directly to the network interface, you don't need htonl (and htons etc).